# How to implement playbook _ My command "cluster run vm_status.py" asking a password

Tags: ansible, cluster-computing

I want to develop playbook/task for the below command

```
Command: cluster run verify_vm_status.py
```

This cluster command has a password. When we type this command it will ask us a password , after entering password it will display the output

I tried expect module but my target is not installed with pexpect.
I have set up ssh between ansible control node and target. I have used some ssh tricks it's working manually. But in the playbook it is not working.

I tried delegate_to option and i have performed the below commands:

```
- name: Verify VM Status
  shell: |
   eval "$(ssh-agent)"
   ssh-add /home/mahesh/.ssh/id_rsa
   ssh-add -l -E md5
   ssh admin@10.11.2.123 -A cluster run verify_vm_status.py
  register: results
  delegate_to: 10.11.2.123
- debug: msg="{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

Manually the above steps are working

Comment: eval "$(ssh-agent)"

ssh-add /home/mahesh/.ssh/id_rsa

ssh-add -l -E md5

ssh admin@10.11.2.123 -A cluster run verify_vm_status.py   ---> Its working manually ---> If i run this locally using delegate option in playbbok i was getting not reachable error. I have ssh connectivity between two nodes

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find solution for this issue:

ssh admin@ip -t "ssh user@ip 'echo  | "

Here admin is my jump server
here user is my target node.

Now Write your playbook like this
- name: Verify VM Status
  shell: ssh {{ cic2_user }}@{{ cic2_ip }} -t "ssh {{ aBgf_user }}@{{ aBgf_ip }} 'echo {{ aBgf_password }} | cluster run sudo shutdown -r'"
  register: result
  delegate_to: localhost
- debug: msg="{{ result.stdout_lines }}"

Why this works?
-> The python file uses the getpass module which is completely dependent on the underlining terminal we are using to execute our commands. As we are trying to run this command directly on target node, Ansible generates command something like this ssh user@target_node_ip -t 'cluster_command'. This assigns a pseudo terminal which is making getpass module to asks for a prompt by ignoring the redirection. So removing the -t option removes terminal thereby forcing getpass to call different function and thereby allowing the redirection. I hope this works for everyone

Comment: admin is the user. `ip` is the host.

Comment: This is the final command after troubleshooting:                                                  
 ssh {{ cic2_user }}@{{ cic2_ip }} -t "ssh {{ aBgf_user }}@{{ aBgf_ip }} 'echo {{ aBgf_password }} | cluster run sudo shutdown -r'"

Comment: cic2 user is my jump server, bgf user is my target server.

Comment: Gitlab===>DDS  ===> CIC ===> target(bgf)